# How to replace the first occurrence in a string?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I am trying to replace every question mark "?" in a string with a values in an array.

I need to go through a string, and replace the first occurrence of '?' in the string with a value. I would need to do that for every occurrence

Here is what I tried

```
function sprintf2($str='', array $values = array(), $char = '?')
{
    if (!$str){
        return '';
    }

    if (count($values) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($values as $value)
        {
            $str = preg_replace('/'. $char . '/', $value, $str, 1);
        }
    }

    echo $str;
}
```

But I am getting the following exception

> preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

The following shows how I am calling the function

```
    $bindings = array(10, 500);
    $str = "select * from `survey_interviews` where `survey_id` = ? and `call_id` = ? limit 1";
    sprintf2($str, $bindings);
```

What am I doing wrong here? why do I get this exception?

Comment: You might benefit from prepared statements. Check out this [example at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-983). And [this one](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1025).

Comment: @showdev I actually want to print the actual query that is being executed at the server. I want to print it in a plain text to evaluate it's value

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`, since you're replacing a literal string, not a regular expression pattern.

However, `str_replace` always replaces all matches, there's no way to limit it to just the first match (`preg_replace` is similar). The 4th argument is not a limit, it's a variable that gets set to the number of matches that were found and replaced. To replace just one match, you can combine `strpos` and `substr_replace`:

```
function sprintf2($str='', array $values = array(), $char = '?')
{
    if (!$str){
        return '';
    }

    if (count($values) > 0)
    {
        $len = strlen($char);
        foreach ($values as $value)
        {
            $pos = strpos($str, $char);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $str = substr_replace($str, $value, $pos, strlen($char));
            }
        }
    }

    echo $str;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/pzirLS)

Comment: Agreed. "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace()." [str_replace @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: @Barmar this is not working for me. first I hd to replace the number 1 with a value that has the number 1 as a value. Now it seems to be replacing every occurrence with the same value. based on the docs your code should work. This is my code `$count = 1;

     foreach ($bindings as $value)
        {
         $sql = str_replace('?', $value, $sql, $count);
        }

        echo $sql .'<br>';`

Comment: We both misunderstood the `$count` argument to `str_replace` and `preg_replace`. It's not a limit on the number of replacements, it's a reference parameter that gets the number of replacements that were made.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the '?' sign in your regexp using a backslash ( '\?' instead of '?').

But your code can be easily refactored to use preg_replace_callback instead:

```
$params = array(1, 3);
$str = '? bla ?';
echo preg_replace_callback('#\?#', function() use (&$params) {
    return array_pop($params);
}, $str);
```

Comment: Since the function takes the string as a parameter, you should use `preg_quote` to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you.

```
function sprintf2($string = '', array $values = array(), $char = '?')
{
    if (!$string){
        return '';
    }

    if (count($values) > 0)
    {
        $exploded = explode($char, $string);
        $i = 0;
        $string = '';
        foreach ($exploded as $segment) {
            if( $i < count($values)){
                $string .= ($segment . $values[$i]);
                ++$i;
            }

        }
    }

    echo $string;
}

$bindings = array(10, 500);
$str = "select * from `survey_interviews` where `survey_id` = ? and `call_id`= ? limit 1";
echo sprintf2($str, $bindings);
```

**Explanation:** 

In your code, you're using the preg_match and the first parameter in the preg_match method is a regex pattern. what you're trying to replace is **?** has a valid meaning for **0 or 1 CHARACTER**. So, you've to escape that by doing **\?**. Though all the characters are not needed to be escaped, so, for making your method work, you've to check the character that are valid for any regex. 

In my code, I've split the string for the character you want. then appending the values at the end of the part what we get from the array. and this should be done till the values length of the value array, otherwise the offset error will occur.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?